# Is "sharedhovercard.js" part of SharePoint's default installation?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, javascript, deployment, installation

I've been alerted that a security scan found a vulnerability in one of our SharePoint farms that there is an out of date version of jQuery (which presents a security risk).

The file in question is located at:

```
https://<server>/_layouts/15/sharedhovercard.js
```

Inspection of the file reveals a *comment* inside it that reads:

```
/*! jQuery v1.7.2 jquery.com */
```

which I believe is what the security scan found.

Other people have also been reporting this same issue:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/out-of-date-version-jquery/m-p/1663933

Clearly, a comment inside a `.js` file referencing a specific jQuery version does not necessarily mean that that version of jQuery is being used anywhere, but even so, I started wondering about that file.

The location (*directly* in `/_layouts/15`) is **not** somewhere that I would put anything custom that I deployed, even if it were a Farm solution and I was deploying files to the `_layouts` folder.  It seems like somewhere that some file included by Microsoft as part of the regular installation of SharePoint might end up, however, I've been working with SharePoint for a while and I've never heard of `sharedhovercard.js`.

Is that a file that is included with a regular installation of SharePoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just check my SharePoint 16/19 enviroments. The file `sharedhovercard.js` seems to be included with the installation of SharePoint.

Actually, the path of the file in local machine is:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\sharedhovercard.js
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I also found the file at the location you indicated on the two 2016 environments I have access to... and they both have the same "modified" date and time as in your screenshot (2/9/2016 6:00 AM), so I am taking that as an indication that yes, the file is included in a regular SP 2016 installation.

Answer (score 2):

**Is “sharedhovercard.js” part of SharePoint's default installation?**

It's not a part of the default **SharePoint 2013** Installation, and this file is not found on my side!

[image]

Also, I have checked the physical layout path, I can't find it!

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS
```

> It would be also great to share the current SharePoint version and the latest Cumulative update that is currently installed (check how you can **[Find SharePoint Farm Build Version](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)**). So that we can investigate further.